# Dimensionality and Subspace Existence: A Potential Outlet for Disquisition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The subset of $F^n$ consisting of all vectors $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=0$ is a subspace of $F^n$ and its dimension is ...(**?**)....

---

Initially, my intuition said the dimension is $2n$ and that the set is $\{v \in F: v=-v\}$.

---

In retrospect, I believe the set here is $S=\{v=(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in F^n : a_1+\cdots+a_n=0\}$, correct?

---

How must one demonstrate subspace existence?

Answer (score 2):

No. The set $\{v \in F^n \mid v = -v\}$ contains vectors $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ with the property $(a_1, \dots, a_n) = - (a_1, \dots, a_n)$. If the field $F$ has characteristic other than $2$, this is only the zero vector. Even if the characteristic of $F$ is $2$, it contains other elements, but they may not be in the set $\{(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in F^n \mid a_1 + \dots + a_n = 0\}$. For example, $(0, 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_2^2$ and $(0, 1) = - (0, 1)$ but $(0, 1) \notin \{(a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb{Z}_2^2 \mid a_1 + a_2 = 0\}$.

Instead, consider this: If $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is a vector such that $a_1 + \dots + a_n = 0$ do you need to know all of the $n$ numbers $a_1, \dots, a_n$ to figure out what the vector is, or can you do it with less?

Comment: So $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is $\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}$ and not $(a_1=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \end{pmatrix}, \dots, a_n=\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1 \\ \vdots \\ \omega_n \end{pmatrix})$, right? Actually, I think I know the answer to that...

Comment: In your question, $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is an element of the vector space $F^n$. As such, the components $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are elements of the field $F$, they are not themselves vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S \subset F^n$, where $S = \{v=(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in F^n : a_1+\cdots+a_n=0\}$, and let $v_1,v_2 \in S$ and $c \in F$.

**Subspace Test**

(*i*) It is easy to show that $z=(0,\dots,0) \in S$ because certainly $0+\cdots+0=0$

(*ii*) To show that $cv_1+v_2 \in S$, consider the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
c(a_1,\dots,a_n)+(b_1,\dots,b_n)=(ca_1+b_1,ca_2+b_2,\dots,ca_n+b_n),
\end{eqnarray}
which by the properties of $S$ must satisfy
\begin{eqnarray}
(ca_1+b_1)+(ca_2+b_2)+\cdots+(ca_n+b_n)=0.
\end{eqnarray}
Clearly, this can be rearranged via the commutativity of addition into the form
\begin{eqnarray}
(ca_1+ca_2+\cdots+ca_n)+(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n)=0,
\end{eqnarray}
and again under distributivity, namely
\begin{eqnarray}
c(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)^{*}+(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n)^{**}=0.
\end{eqnarray}
Now, all the $a_i$'s in (*) are elements of the field $F$ for which $v_1$ is in $S$, thus $a_1+\cdots+a_n=0$, which applies just the same to the $b_i$'s in (**). Hence, $cv_1+v_2 \in S$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:F^n\to F$ defined by $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=a_1+\cdots+a_n$. You can easily prove that $f$ is a (surjective) linear map and $S=\ker f$. This shows that $S$ is a subspace of $F^n$ and $\dim S=n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**THEOREM**

*The subset of $F^n$ consisting of all vectors $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=0$ is a subspace of $F^n$ and its dimension is $n-1$.*

Using what some of you have hinted at I'll use the below definitions—from Friedberg's "Linear Algebra" and Hoffmann's "Linear Algebra" respectively—as a guide:

---

**Definitions.** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be linear. We define the **null space** (or **kernel**) $N(T)$ of $T$ to be the set of all vectors $x$ in $V$ such that $T(x)=0$; that is $N(T)=\{x\in V:T(x)=0\}$. We define the **range** (or **image**) $R(T)$ of $T$ to be the subset of $W$ consisting of all images (under $T$) of vectors in $V$; that is, $R(T)=\{T(x):x\in V\}$.

---

**Definition.** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the field $F$ and let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ into $W$. The **null space** of $T$ is the set of all vectors $\alpha$ in $V$ such that $T\alpha = 0$.

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, the **rank** of $T$ is the dimension of the range of $T$ and the **nullity** of $T$ is the dimension of the null space of $T$.

The following is one of the most important results in linear algebra.

**Theorem 2.** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the field $F$ and let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ into $W$. Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
rank(T)+nulilty(T)=\dim(V).
\end{eqnarray}

---

**PROOF**

With sufficient help from the members in this discussion—and the definitions above—I come to the following—simple—conclusion:

Let $T:F^n \rightarrow F$ be defined by $T(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$. The set $S=\{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n) \in F^n : a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=0\}$ is clearly, by definition, $N(T)$, the described set in THEOREM. By the rank-nullity theorem we have that

\begin{eqnarray}
\dim R(T) + \dim N(T) = \dim V \leadsto \dim F + \dim N(T) = n \leadsto \dim N(T) = n-1
\end{eqnarray}

because $\dim F^1 = 1$.

Comment: Yes, sure! But don't forget to mention that you finally understood my answer and liked it so much that you felt the need to post it as your own answer.